# Are [ "$VAR" = "" ] and [ -z "$VAR" ] always equivalent?

Tags: shell-script

My code looks something like this:

```
VAR=""

while [ -z "$VAR" ]; do
  VAR=$( command | grep "important_string" )
done
```

So I want to poll the output of `command`, until the `important_string` appears and put into `$VAR`.

Is there any functional difference between `[ -z "$VAR" ]` and `[ "$VAR" = "" ]`?

Comment: `==` is incorrect syntax, but works in many shells (presumably because it's muscle memory to anyone using other languages). You should be using `=`.

Comment: @l0b0 copied the `==` from somewhere. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they ( `[ -z "$VAR" ]` and `[ "$VAR" = "" ]` ...) are equivalent. Both are testing for emptiness of `$VAR` (e.g. when it is not bound, or set to an empty string).

As commented by [Celada](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14034/celada), bad things might happen when using `[ "$VAR" = "" ]`  if `VAR` is some valid test (e.g. if `VAR` is `-z`), in particular when `[` (or `test`) is *not* a shell builtin. But on `bash` or `zsh` the `[` is a builtin and that does not seem to be an issue. You could use `[ "x$VAR" = "x" ]` for your test. See [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)

Of course, I am assuming some POSIX shell or something similar.

Perhaps `-z` might be slightly faster (but you should not care about microseconds in shell scripts) and you might find `=` to perhaps be more readable.

Comment: I though for sure that `[ "$VAR" = "" ]` was wrong because if the contents of `$VAR` were to start with a hyphen then it would lead to a syntax error, for example if `$VAR` contains `-z` then it would expand to `[ -z = "" ]` — would that test if `=` is empty (which it isn't) and then treat `""` as an extraneous argument? But I cannot seem to make it fail that way now that I try it after reading your answer! I've been using contructs like `[ "x$VAR" = "xfoo" ]` to guard against special characters in `$VAR` for decades, perhaps unnecessarily!

Comment: @Celada: I think your point is true for the rare shells where `test` is not a builtin.

Comment: I think that regarding expansions shell built-ins should behave the same way as external commands. Did not you confuse it with keywords like `[[` in bash? They are really different. --- I do not observe any special behaviour regarding the variable expansion with the `test` build-in of bash.

Comment: I tested with `zsh`

Comment: @Celada actually, you are right, there are just so many things that could go wrong using `[ "$VAR" = "" ]` that is safer to use `-z` instead.

Comment: @Celada All POSIX shells are required to parse this correctly, and AFAIK non-antique shells all do. Some Bourne variants did fail in ways like what you describe, which led to the `"x$VAR"` habits. Complex cases involving `-a` or `-o` can trip up even modern shells, but for that the remedy is to use `&&` or `||` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Gilles. While I don't know whether or not I have ever personally programmed with a shell that was antique enough to trigger that problem, I learned the habit from a mentor who surely did.